# Google Glass remote authentication

Tags: google-glass

I am looking at the remote authentication API provided by  https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/authentication.

Here are the first two steps, as documented on the website:

```
1. When users turn on your Glassware in MyGlass, they are redirected to your authentication URL.
2. The user enters their credentials on your authentication page.
```

I am confused on how one can achieve the second part. There is no keyboard or any other way to type in keys on Glass. How can one enter the credentials? Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyGlass is not *on glass*.  The my glass interface is either through the myglass website or via the my glass android application.  So you never turn on glassware inside glass itself, you do it externally on a device that does have the ability to handle the transaction.  Once done, the glassware (and, in this case any authentication and configuration info you set) gets pushed to your glass behind the scenes.